# Receive ImportError: cannot import name 'DictVectorizer'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have installed scikit-learn to a python environment through Anaconda. This is on Ubuntu 14.04.  The line in my code it is complaining about is

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import DictVectorizer
```

The error is

```
Import Error: cannot import name 'DictVectorizer'
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both using Conda and then with Pip.  The install succeeds with no error no matter how I install it.

If I start a python command line and type the import, no errors are given.

Would anyone have any suggestions for how to be able to import the DictVectorizer in my code?

Comment: check your pythonpath

Comment: You might have multiple installations of Python. How do you start it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with that library. However, looking at the source on github it appears you have the import path wrong.

`from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer` should work

Comment: Thanks.  That was exactly it.